# How to perform a weighted overlay analysis with categorical classed data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, union, land-use

I have several land use layers (vector polygons) that all contain a field about land use in different classification systems and would like to combine them to a single classification. I would like to give weights on combining these layers in order to get one "land use" per polygon, but I cannot find out how I can possibly do it.

The weights would rank the reliability/accuracy of a particular classification layer. Let's say layer No1 weights 0.26, layer No2 weights 0.14, layer No3 weights 0.20, layer No4 weights 0.17, and layer No5 weights 0.23. If No1 and No5 class as one use and the other three class as another, the final class chosen would be the other because of the weights.

The problem is that since the classes are categorical, it would be possible via the Weighted Overlay tool to generate an illogical result. Consider the following classes: 1 - crop, 7 - park, 3 - urban. No1 says urban, No2 and No5 say crop, and No3 and No4 say park. The weighted overlay would be `.24*3 + .14*1 + .23*1 + .20*7 + .17*7 = 3.68` round to 4. That would be a completely different land use from any of the original three.

I am working on ArcGIS 10.1 (Advanced / Spatial Analyst activated) but I could follow instructions on QGIS.

Comment: What license level do you have - Basic, Standard, or Advanced? Do you have any extensions available, such as Spatial Analyst? Please edit your question to include this information, as it may affect solutions proposed based on what tools are available. Also, can you describe more what you mean by weighted? Are the weights intended to determine a rank, so higher weight means that land use will be chosen for the final polygon? Or are you making new classifications based on the combination of those weighted factors? Can you tell us what those land use attribute values are?

Comment: I have Advanced licence and Spatial Analyst extension also.
As you mentioned above, the weights are intended to determine a rank, so higher weight means that land use will be chosen for the final polygon based on the combination and the weights of the layers. The land use values are from Eurostat's LUCAS land use classification system and I have inserted Corine LC, Urban Atlas and other classification systems and I intend to take a final result of LUCAS land use polygons.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do but don't know how to solve it. You have several land classifications for a given area and likely have three issues: class boundaries don't line up, classes are not the same, and you may have multiple (very different) classifications for the same area. You want to pick one class based on a weighted study of the different systems. You're trying to do a weighted overlay with definition classes (perhaps wrong term), and that doesn't work with the tool or math.

Comment: You couldn't describe it better. Yes. Thanx, so I will be waiting for any idea.

Comment: I've edited to hopefully clarify the question and attract more attention. I changed the weights because it would have been possible to have a tie between two classes. You could solve the issue of classes not being the same by going through each layer and changing them to match LUCAS (ie if LUCAS has one crop and another system has three, you'd change the three to be one and call it the same as it is in LUCAS), but that only solves one of the three issues. Boundaries not lining up can be solved one of two ways (Union or raster conversion), but the weighted choice part escapes me.

Comment: Since this is not a suitability type analysis I am not sure that a weighted overlay is at all the appropriate approach. You may want to investigate a weighted Kappa.

Comment: I found an article (A methodology to generate a synergetic land-cover map by fusion of different land-cover products. Pérez-Hoyos, A. et al., 2012) dealing this issue, but because of my bad English and math, I am not that capable of understanding their solution. Thanx anyways!