# Extract mean value of a raster into a grid shapefile

Tags: spatial-statistics, gme

I have a soil map of an island and a Grid polygon. I want to extract the mean value of the soil map to polygons squares of grid.

I read [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40536/extract-raster-value-into-polygon-attribute) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1177/how-to-calculate-raster-area-per-polygon) but Ι can't find the results.  I use Geospatial Modeling Environment

`isectpolyrst(in="\~\Polygon_grid.shp", raster="C:\~\TAXGWRB_1km_T453_ProjectRast1.tif", prefix="SOIL", thematic=TRUE, proportion=TRUE);`

`269 polygons processed.`

But can’t find the export or the results.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'can't find the results'? Have you tried the Zonal Statistics tool in ArcGIS as suggested by the first question you link to? Or have you only tried the GME tool? From the help it looks like the result is added to the polygons as an attribute, not a separate file. What would a 'mean value' give you on categorical (soil type) data, or are you looking at properties of the types such as pH? This seems related to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123103/ but I'm not entirely clear on what you want to do.